# How to call API inside React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a scenario like need to call API inside the React function component. If possible how to return the result. I could be able to call the API but the response is available in the variable. Please advise

My sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import axios from 'axios';

const Table = (props) => {
  const getData = [axios.get("https://lq-time- 
    tracking.firebaseio.com/user.json").then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })]    

 const data = [{getData}];       
 const columns = [{
    id: 'Name',
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: data.user
  }, {
    Header: 'Date',
    accessor: 'Date',
  }, {
    Header: 'Comment',
    accessor:'Comment' 
  }]

  return <ReactTable
    data={...data}
    columns={columns}
    pivotBy={ ['Date', 'Name']}
  />
}       
export default Table;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll likely want to use a couple hooks; `useEffect` to do the API querying and `useState` to store the data. The empty dependency array in the `useEffect` hook will make sure the API call is only made when the component mounts. Then, when the call resolves, the data is set to a stateful variable called `data`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import axios from 'axios';

const Table = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com/user.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        setData(response.data);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);

  const columns = [{
    id: 'Name',
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: data.user
  }, {
    Header: 'Date',
    accessor: 'Date',
  }, {
    Header: 'Comment',
    accessor:'Comment' 
  }]

  return <ReactTable
    data={...data}
    columns={columns}
    pivotBy={ ['Date', 'Name']}
  />
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(
       (result) => {
         this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           items: result.items
         });
       },
       // Note: it's important to handle errors here
       // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
       // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
       (error) => {
         this.setState({
           isLoaded: true,
           error
         });
       }
     )
 }
```